# Run Maven without Windows variables?

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

I want to get a *.jar from this: https://github.com/nicknux/pdfboxer

I don't want to add windows variables to run Maven, just unpack the zip, because I won't use my Maven later.

I have downloaded pdfboxer to:
C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\pdfboxer-master

and maven to:
C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\apache-maven-3.6.2

Jag get the error:

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
>   is no POM in this directory
>   (C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin). Please verify
>   you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

When I write this in Windows command promt (cmd)

```
C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin>mvn c:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\pdfboxer-master\pom.xml clean package
```

Comment: Have you tried running from the project's directory and fully specifying the path to `mvn` instead?

Comment: I would suggest to use `mvn -f PathToYourPomFile/pom.xml clean package` but I would suggest to change into the directory and just use `mvn clean package`...it's easier...you can also change into the directory given and use `C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\mvn clean package` ...easiest is to add the bin part to your PATH ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to the project directory:

```
cd "c:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\pdfboxer-master"
```

Then run maven build like this:

```
"C:\Users\sig\Downloads\pdfbox\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\mvn" clean package
```